# How to enforce a FileBackupAgent to run?

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm developing an app with backup feature.  I can't use AutoBackup because I intend it to be used on KitKat devices, and autobackup only works with Android Marshmallow and up.
So I registered my app on Google Backup, made my BackupAgentHelper class and everything is alright and working.
Only doubt here is (and I can't find answers anywhere): is there a way to make the backup run RIGHT NOW programatically?
I know I can use

```
adb shell bmgr run
```

on a terminal, but I intend my app to do it when the user clicks on BACKUP MY DATA.  If there's no connection, it's perfectly alright to leave it on queue to be backup up when Android decides to, but if the device is online, I really need the app to push the backup to internet right away, so the user can uninstall the app and destroy the phone if he feels like it at that very moment.
Any help will be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: I connect my KitKat physical device to PC.  I execute 
`adb shell bmgr list transports` 
and this is the output, which seems ok.

```
 * com.google.android.backup/.BackupTransportService
android/com.android.internal.backup.LocalTransport
```

Then I execute `adb shell bmgr enabled` and this is the output, which seems ok.

```
Backup Manager currently enabled
```

Then I execute adb shell dumpsys backup and this is the output, which seems ok.

```
Backup Manager is enabled / provisioned / not pending init
Auto-restore is enabled
Last backup pass started: 1528290895418 (now = 1528291313245)
  next scheduled: -9223372036854525445
Available transports:
  * com.google.android.backup/.BackupTransportService
       destination: myaccount@gmail.com
       intent: Intent { act=com.google.android.backup.SetBackupAccountActivity }
    {blah blah blah, not my app anywhere}
android/com.android.internal.backup.LocalTransport
   destination: Backing up to debug-only private cache
   intent: null
Pending init: 0
Participants:
  {blah blah blah, and my app down here}
  uid: 10281
    com.mydomain.myapp
Ancestral packages: none
Ever backed up: 12
    {blah blah blah, not my app anywhere}
Pending backup: 18
    {blah blah blah, and my app down here}
    BackupRequest{pkg=com.mydomain.myapp}
```

Is it ok to have such a negative number after `next scheduled`??

Anyway, then I execute `adb shell bmgr run`, and there is no output.

And then again, `adb shell dumpsys backup`, with almost the same output as before executing bmgr run (it only changes these first lines)

```
Last backup pass started: 1528291863806 (now = 1528291916809)
```

next scheduled: -9223372036854548598

I really don't understand if it is backing up or not.  Apparently, it's not, because when I run `adb uninstall com.mydomain.myapp` and then reinstalls it, it wouldn't restore a thing. And if I, after reinstalling, run `adb shell bmgr restore com.mydomain.myapp`, the output is

```
Unable to restore package com.mydomain.myapp
done
```

I don't know what to do.  Really, I'm totally lost on this.

This is my FileBackupAgent class:

```
public class MyBackupAgent extends BackupAgentHelper{
private String FILENAME_OF_JSON_DATA;
static final String BACKUP_KEY = "JSONBackup";

@Override
public void onCreate(){
    FILENAME_OF_JSON_DATA = this.getResources().getString( R.string.app_name ) + ".json";
    FileBackupHelper fileBackupHelper = new FileBackupHelper( this, FILENAME_OF_JSON_DATA );
    addHelper( BACKUP_KEY, fileBackupHelper );
}
```

This is my manifest (the important part of it)

```
    <application
    android:name=".MyAppName"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:backupAgent=".Utils.MyBackupAgent"
    android:restoreAnyVersion="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".Activities.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.backup.api_key"
        android:value="mykeyhere"
    />
```

Comment: Your post contains two questions.  Please split your post up, so that you have one question per post.

Comment: Also:  KitKat is quite old, and not commonly used anymore.  I understand that you want your app to _run_ on KitKat; but why do you even want backups to work on KitKat?

Comment: I'm in the same situation right now with my app.. Did you find any solution?